# How to write a function that imports a Python script by absolute path

Tags: python, python-import

I need to write a function that imports a python script by absolute path. For example

```
my_path = "/my/path/to/python/script.py"

def import_script_by_absolute_path(path):
    ???

my_script = import_script_by_absolute_path(my_path)
print(my_script.my_sum(2, 2))
# prints 4
```

`/my/path/to/python/script.py` contains:

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

UPD: Alternatively, you can suggest a function from a library that does it

UPD2: The question you lead to doesn't solve my problem. I need a function exactly and I can't understand how to do a function from the answers to this question

Comment: In the future, please start with your own research. If you just google part of your title, `How to import a Python script by absolute path`, you find useful results including that question.

Comment: Regarding your edit, what did you try exactly? Show us the code you tried.

Comment: I can't edit my question because "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening"

Comment: So I can't add what I tried

Comment: @wjandrea I know how to import a python script by absolute path. I don't know how to make a function, and I need a function!

Comment: Oh, I see. That's not the actual reason, but there's a major sitewide problem going on right now. So... maybe try back in an hour :|

Comment: FYI, the problem has been reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381510/343832) if you want to track the status

Comment: The problem should be resolved now

Comment: @wjandrea no, it's not

Comment: Looks like you've [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73479329/how-to-write-a-function-that-imports-a-python-script-by-absolute-path). So please delete this question then. That'll prevent further downvotes and save the work of the reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add it to sys's path variable:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/foo/bar/my_module')
import my_module
```

Comment: I need a function exactly and the only input is path to the script. In your answer you type "my_module" yourself